# Explain the syntax of Collections.<String>emptyList()

Tags: java, generics, collections

I just studied about generic programming, the `List<E>` interface, and `ArrayList`, so I can understand the statement below.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

But I don't understand the next statement which I saw while surfing the web.

```
List<String> list2 = Collections.<String>emptyList();
```

1. What is `Collections`? Why isn't it `Collections<E>` or `Collections<String>`?
2. Why is `<String>` placed before the method name `emptyList`?

(Isn't `emptyList<String>()` correct for Generic?)

3. What does the statement mean?

Comment: [`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) is a Java class.

Comment: The `Collection` is the interface and `collections` is a static class which contains all methods

Comment: **This is a perfectly valid question**. Not sure it was treated so harshly. To someone who doesn't understand static method generics, it could be a confusing statement. Voting to re-open.

Comment: Also voted to reopen.   The _title_ of the question is too broad, probably, but the actual question in the body is pretty specific.   Perhaps editing the title is better than closing.

Comment: Seems to me that the number of concepts that need to be explained to answer this question is so high that an answer would almost constitute an intro Java tutorial. But [here's my explanation of generic methods](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21298123/402884). As for question 2, read about static imports.

Comment: @ChrisMartin I think it is pretty borderline. I feel like the question was direct enough to reopen though.

Comment: @ChrisMartin See given answers. They seem to do a pretty good job. OP understands generics, but *method* generics is an (understandably) new concept that aren't as common in the wild.

Comment: Check this [link](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/carcassi/archive/2010/04/09/two-problems-generics-java-0)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

That line creates an empty list of strings by calling a static method with a generic type parameter.

Inside the `Collections` class, there is a static method `emptyList` declared like:

```
public static final <T> List<T> emptyList() {
    return (List<T>) EMPTY_LIST;
}
```

This has a generic type parameter `T`. We call call this method by using:

```
List<String> list = Collections.emptyList();
```

and `T` is infered to be a `String` because of the type of `list`.

We can also specify the type of `T` by putting it in angle brackets when calling `emptyList`. This may be needed if we want a more specific type than is inferred:

```
List<? extends Object> list = Collections.<String>emptyList();
```

`emptyList<String>()` is not correct because that placement is only valid when creating
instances of generic classes, not calling methods. When using `new` there are two possible
type parameters, the ones before the class name are for the constructor only, and the ones after the class name are for the whole instance, so with the class:

```
class MyClass<A> {
    public <B> MyClass(A a, B b) {
        System.out.println(a + ", " + b);
    }
}
```

We can call its constructor where `A` is `String` and `B` is `Integer` like:

```
MyClass<String> a = new <Integer>MyClass<String>("a", 3);
```

or by using type inference:

```
MyClass<String> a = new MyClass<>("a", 3);
```

**See also:**

- [Generic Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html)
- [Type Inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)

Comment: Might want to mention `Collections` is one of those classes that is there *only* to provide static methods; it's not intended to be instantiated itself (and can't be, in turn).

Comment: I'm no Java expert but it seems to me, then, that `foo<T>()` is _not_ "calling a constructor" at all, even though the resulting object construction results in an invocation of `foo`'s constructor (among all the other steps taken to instantiate a `foo`). Then there is no actual inconsistency or discrepancy against the generic method call syntax `<T>bar()` (which, coming from a C++ background, is mighty weird let me just say!).

Comment: I checked the constructor syntax, and it turns out that constructors can have their own type parameters too, so we can have syntax containing two type parameter expressions like `new <String>MyClass<Integer>(2)`.

Comment: @fgb Huh... that's new. I guess I've never seen something like that in the wild. Interesting!

Comment: "emptyList<String>() is not correct because that placement is only valid when calling constructors, not static methods" This statement is confusing; since this question is about generic methods, it sounds like you are talking about generic constructors. But you are not. `SomeClass<String>()` is for creating an instance of a generic class with a non-generic constructor. To create an instance of a class using a generic constructor, you would do something like `new <String> SomeClass()`.

Answer (score 11):

> What is `Collections`? Why isn't it `Collections<E>` or `Collections<String>`?

[`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) is a JDK class.

> This class consists exclusively of static methods that operate on or
>   return collections. It contains polymorphic algorithms that operate on
>   collections, "wrappers", which return a new collection backed by a
>   specified collection, and a few other odds and ends.

It's not generic and cannot be instantiated.

> Why is `<String>` placed before the method name `emptyList`?

[`Collections#emptyList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList--) is a generic method. Here, we are explicitly specifying a type argument, `String`.

> (Isn't `emptyList<String>()` correct for Generic?)

No, in Java, generic type arguments for methods come before the method name.

> What does the statement mean?

We are invoking the static `emptyList` method and assigning its return value to a variable of type `List<String>`.

Answer (score 9):

**In a nutshell, this creates an empty, immutable list of strings.**

Let's look at the expression bit by bit.

[`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) is the name of a class. From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html):

> This class consists exclusively of static methods that operate on or return collections. It contains polymorphic algorithms that operate on collections, "wrappers", which return a new collection backed by a specified collection, and a few other odds and ends.

[`emptyList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList--) is the name of a static method defined in the `Collections` class ([Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList--)). It is a generic method, and the `<String>` in `Collections.<String>emptyList()` specifies the generic type argument.

The method returns a `List<T>`, which in this case is `List<String>`: a list of strings. More specifically, it returns an *empty*, *immutable* list of strings.

Comment: `+1` for highlighting (although present in the docs) *immutability* of the returned collection.

Answer (score 6):

1.Collection is an interface and collections is a static class consists exclusively of static methods that operate on or return collections. Hence we cannot use `Collections<E>` or `Collections<String>`.

2.`<String>` before emptyList(used to get the empty list that is immutable) denotes that only String values can be added to it. Like:

```
list2.add("A");
list2.add("B");
```

3.The statement means that it will create a immutable empty list of type List.

You can check out this link: [Difference between Java Collection and Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796275/difference-between-java-collection-and-collections)

Comment: `denotes that only String values can be added to it.` A more precise description is that: it declares the parameter type of the method to be String, so that the return value is a homogeneous List of String.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, `Collections` is a helper library of static methods that operate on various types of collections. If you've done any sort of C++ programming, it's very synonymous to the `<algorithm>` library of functions.

In this case, you're invoking the static method `emptyList()`, which returns an empty list of a particular type. Since these methods still require a type, but `Collections`' methods can refer to many types, you have to specify the type upon invocation.

In order to call a generic *method*, you must call it with the parameter list (i.e. `<String>`) *before* the method name, but *after* the dot.

```
List<String> someList = Collections.<String>emptyList();
```